# Digikey like parametric internal parts search software

Tags: components

I am looking for software that  essentially duplicated digikey/octopart's parametric parts search, but filters on an internal parts list that we already have.
Is there any commercial or open source software that accomplishes this internal electronics parts search?
Ideally self hosted.

There are many an electronic parts catalog (EPC) software, but none really seem to have parametric search down, especially for electronic components specifically.

Comment: yes. But it's expensive

Comment: Cost is not necessarily an issue for an existing product. Do you have some examples / recommendations? My searches thus far have been fruitless for anything of any cost.